# Fill NULL rows based on some mathematical operations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table **A** which contains `id` and `report_day` and other columns. Also I've a table **B** which contains also `id`, `report_day` and also `subscribers`. I want to create a VIEW with `id, report_day, subscribers` columns. So it's a simple join:

```
select a.id, a.report_day, b.subscribers  from schema.a
left join schema.b on a.id = b.id 
and a.report_day = b.report_day
```

[image: view]

Now i want to add column `subscribers_increment` based on `subscribers`. But for some days I don't have stats for `subscribers` column and it's set to `NULL`. `subcribers_increment` it's just a *(subcribers(current_day) - subscribers (prev_day).*

I read some articles and add next statement:

```
case WHEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY b.report_day ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) = 1 THEN b.subscribers
else ab.subscribers - COALESCE(last_value(b.subscribers) OVER (PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY b.report_day ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0::bigint::numeric)
END::integer AS subscribers_increment
```

And now I've next result:

[image: increment]

`NULL` is still `NULL`.
For example it has incorrect `increment` for `2021-04-07`. It's increment for 2 days. Can i divide this value from `2021-04-08` by numbers of days (here it's 2) and write same value for `2021-04-07` and `2021-04-08` (or at least for `2021-04-07` where it was null)? And same logic for all days where `subscribers` is null?

**So i need to follow next rules:
If I see `NULL` value in `subcribers` column I should go for the next (future) NOT NULL day and grab value for this next day. Substract from this (feature) value last not null value (past - order by date, so we looping back). Divide result of substraction by number of days and fill these rows for column `subcribers_increment`.**

Is it possible?

**UPDATE:**

For my data it shoud look like this:

[image]

**UPDATE v2**

After applying script:
[image]

**UPDATE v3**

case (our increment) 25.03-27.03 still is NULL
[image]

Comment: A few rows of sample data just illustrating what you want to do would be very helpful.  If I understand correctly, you want interpolation.  However, what you really want isn't clearly shown in the question.

Comment: I added `result` table what i expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is:

1. Use `lag()` to get the  previous `subscribers` and dates before joining.  This assumes that the `left join` is the cause of all the `NULL` values.
2. Use a cumulative count in reverse to assign a grouping so `NULL` is combined with the next value in one grouping.
3. As a result of (2), the count of `NULL`s in a group is the denominator
4. As a result of (1) the difference between `subscribers` and `prev_subscribers` is the numerator.
5. The actual calculation requires more window functions and case logic.

So the idea is:

```
with t as (
      select a.id, a.report_day, b.subscribers, b.prev_report_day, b.prev_subscribers,
             count(b.subscribers) over (partition by a.id order by a.report_day desc) as grp
      from first_table a left join
           (select b.*,
                   lag(b.report_day) over (partition by id order by report_day) as prev_report_day,
                   lag(b.subscribers) over (partition by id order by report_day) as prev_subscribers
            from second_table b
           ) b
           on a.id = b.id and a.report_day = b.report_day 
     )
select t.*,
       (case when t.subscribers is not null and t.prev_report_day = t.report_day - interval '1 day'
             then t.subscribers - t.prev_subscribers
             when t.subscribers is not null
             then (t.subscribers - t.prev_subscribers) / count(*) over (partition by id, grp)
             when t.subscribers is null
             then (max(t.subscribers) over (partition by id, grp) - max(t.prev_subscribers) over (partition by id, grp)
                  ) / count(*) over (partition by id, grp)
        end)
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1e7a567079aaff7db4521e7205f196b1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this script (with some syntax fixes) and i got result that i didn't expect (screen in update section).

Comment: @ChokkiAST . . . Please set up a db<>fiddle with sample data.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it in db fidle. Results are different. I got what i expected for 2 days, but some of days is still null. Here is example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=aDlfmeMATS

Comment: @ChokkiAST . . . I adapted your Fiddle to Postgres and adjusted the query for the data.  It seems to be working.

Comment: Great! Did link changed? Because I can't join to room above. It redirects to page without any data.

Comment: @ChokkiAST . . . Use the link in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I see. It puts correct increment for `2021-04-07` and `2021-04-08`, exactly what i wanted. But there is no increment for 25.03 - 28.03 dates, i guess because here we don't have correct inerval (start is null). Is it possible to fill information for these dates too in the same way? I expect to divide `870507` by 3 for 25.03-28.03 dates. Kinda same logic, but without substraction?

Comment: @ChokkiAST . . . Please ask another question about that particular issue . . . along with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I provided additional screenshot with this issue and desired result.